# Is OpenCTM sill under active development?

Tags: file-format

After struggling with `*.3ds` files, which I could not export as I wanted, and `*.obj` files for which I haven't found an available library, I continue the search for a file format for my little game engine.

I heard about [OpenCTM](http://openctm.sourceforge.net/) which sounds like a promising solution to me. It's just for storing vertices but I could totally live with that. And I like the API which is quite similar to the OpenGL api. It also comes with a viewer and importer/exporter.

But of course I wouldn't like to rely on a dead file format. According to what I've [seen on Github](https://github.com/valette/OpenCTM), the last change was at the beginning of 2010. So my question is if OpenCTM is sill under active development and I could therefore use it without doubt in my game engine.

Comment: http://assimp.sourceforge.net/ to import various formats.  use this to convert to a custom, efficient-for-your-engine format for production releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it seems that OpenCTM development has stopped. Looking on their Sourceforge, Github repo and around the internet in general, it seems to have ceased. That said, there are still some people using it, as there was [recently a Javascript port](http://code.google.com/p/js-openctm/), and you could continue developing your own version of it (it doesn't look too complicated at first sight).

Comment: Thanks, could I ask you for a personal estimation, if it's worth to rely with your whole game engine on this format?

Comment: @sharethis It depends, really. I'm working on a game engine currently (indeed programming for that as I type this), and I've taken to using multiple file formats. I've adopted a chunked LOD terrain paging system (much like in Ogre3D) and used .obj for that, although I've ignored the associated .mtl file. On the other hand, I'm using .3ds for models, as it's more compact, though a bit harder for me to get my head around. Rambling finished, my point is that it's best to use multiple file formats, as different formats are better at different things - and that way problems with one won't stop you.

Comment: Alright, I am glad about your answer. Could I contact you by mail? I have a short question about `*.3ds` files that isn't related to this question.

Comment: @sharethis It's on my profile :)

Comment: @danijar Oops, wrong name :P I meant danijar, but sharethis had asked another OpenCTM question.

Comment: That's my fault. Both are me, because I changed my name. I am sorry for the confusion. However, I could find your mail address neither on your profile nor on your website. Am I blind?

Comment: @danijar Doubt it - it isn't on the website, and it's probably hidden on the profile. Use vectuspolaratgmaildotcom.